# How can I change Bluetooth buffer size?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, pipewire

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04. There is a Bluetooth issue in this version that causes the audio streamed from my phone to my Linux desktop to be very laggy (There was not such a problem in the 22.04 version. I also installed Fedora 38 and it was ok too). I want to know how can I increase the Bluetooth buffer size. Is this setting has to be done in Pipewire or do I have to do something with bluez5 API? Or maybe I should install another version of Pipewire (if it is related to Pipewire). My pipe wire version is 0.3.65. Any help is appreciated.